# Is Java code required for AdMob ads?

Tags: android, admob

Is Java code required for AdMob ads? On [developers](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?csw=1) website they use java code, but I tried to load ads just with xml code and it works, just I'm not sure will clicks count. I also noticed that when I was using java code too, that 2 ads were displayed, one behind another.

I'm now using just this:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
.
.
.  
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="..."
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Is this enough or should I also use java code? Here id is not required at all as much as I can see.

Comment: If you see an ad and clicking works then you should be good. I think (sorry I can't be more helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have any Java code to run AdMob adds from `com.google.ads.AdView` (SDK version up to 6.4.1). Your code will function correctly without it if you use `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"`.

You should see the test ads if your using the test mode or the reel ads if you don't. If you see them, it all works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Java code is not required to use `com.google.ads.AdView` but you must include your ad unit ID in order for clicks to be counted. However, `com.google.ads.AdView` is part of the older AdMob Android API. To use the Mobile Ads API in Google Play services you must use Java code. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play) states:

The five lines of code it takes to add a banner:

- Import com.google.android.gms.ads.*
- Declare an AdView instance
- Create it, specifying the ad unit ID
- Add the view to the UI
- Load it with an ad

Comment: Good to know it's changed. I updated my answer to make it correct and +1 for you.